# Convert CVImageBufferRef to CVPixelBufferRef

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation

I am new to iOS programming and multimedia and I was going through a sample project named RosyWriter provided by apple at [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/RosyWriter/Listings/Classes_RosyWriterVideoProcessor_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011110-Classes_RosyWriterVideoProcessor_m-DontLinkElementID_8). Here I saw that in the code there is a function named `captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection` in the code given below:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection 
{   
CMFormatDescriptionRef formatDescription = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(sampleBuffer);

if ( connection == videoConnection ) {
    
    // Get framerate
    CMTime timestamp = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp( sampleBuffer );
    [self calculateFramerateAtTimestamp:timestamp];
    
    // Get frame dimensions (for onscreen display)
    if (self.videoDimensions.width == 0 && self.videoDimensions.height == 0)
        self.videoDimensions = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions( formatDescription );
    
    // Get buffer type
    if ( self.videoType == 0 )
        self.videoType = CMFormatDescriptionGetMediaSubType( formatDescription );

    CVImageBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    
    // Synchronously process the pixel buffer to de-green it.
    [self processPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer];
    
    // Enqueue it for preview.  This is a shallow queue, so if image processing is taking too long,
    // we'll drop this frame for preview (this keeps preview latency low).
    OSStatus err = CMBufferQueueEnqueue(previewBufferQueue, sampleBuffer);
    if ( !err ) {        
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            CMSampleBufferRef sbuf = (CMSampleBufferRef)CMBufferQueueDequeueAndRetain(previewBufferQueue);
            if (sbuf) {
                CVImageBufferRef pixBuf = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sbuf);
                [self.delegate pixelBufferReadyForDisplay:pixBuf];
                CFRelease(sbuf);
            }
        });
    }
}

CFRetain(sampleBuffer);
CFRetain(formatDescription);
dispatch_async(movieWritingQueue, ^{

    if ( assetWriter ) {
    
        BOOL wasReadyToRecord = (readyToRecordAudio && readyToRecordVideo);
        
        if (connection == videoConnection) {
            
            // Initialize the video input if this is not done yet
            if (!readyToRecordVideo)
                readyToRecordVideo = [self setupAssetWriterVideoInput:formatDescription];
            
            // Write video data to file
            if (readyToRecordVideo && readyToRecordAudio)
                [self writeSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer ofType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        }
        else if (connection == audioConnection) {
            
            // Initialize the audio input if this is not done yet
            if (!readyToRecordAudio)
                readyToRecordAudio = [self setupAssetWriterAudioInput:formatDescription];
            
            // Write audio data to file
            if (readyToRecordAudio && readyToRecordVideo)
                [self writeSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer ofType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
        }
        
        BOOL isReadyToRecord = (readyToRecordAudio && readyToRecordVideo);
        if ( !wasReadyToRecord && isReadyToRecord ) {
            recordingWillBeStarted = NO;
            self.recording = YES;
            [self.delegate recordingDidStart];
        }
    }
    CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
    CFRelease(formatDescription);
});
}
```

Here a function named `pixelBufferReadyForDisplay` is called which expects a parameter of type `CVPixelBufferRef`

**Prototype of pixelBufferReadyForDisplay**

```
- (void)pixelBufferReadyForDisplay:(CVPixelBufferRef)pixelBuffer;
```

But in the code above while calling this function it passes the variable `pixBuf` which is of type `CVImageBufferRef`

So my question is that isn't it required to use any function or typecasting to convert a CVImageBufferRef to CVPixelBufferRef or is this done implicitly by the compiler?

Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you do a search on CVPixelBufferRef in the Xcode docs, you'll find the following:

```
typedef CVImageBufferRef CVPixelBufferRef;
```

So a CVImageBufferRef is a synonym for a CVPixelBufferRef. They are interchangeable.

You are looking at some pretty gnarly code. RosyWriter, and another sample app called "Chromakey" do some pretty low-level processing on pixel buffers. If you're new to iOS development AND new to multimedia you might not want to dig so deep, so fast. It's a bit like a first year medical student trying to perform a heart-lung transplant.

Comment: Why is it that you can create a CIImage from a CVPixelBuffer on iOS but not OSX?  CIImage(CVPixelBuffer: currPixelBuffer) works on iOS but not OSX.  CIImage(CVImageBuffer: currPixelBuffer) works on OSX.

Comment: There are some data type difference between the platforms. Sometimes there's no good reason for it.